# sumproduct with if in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gEs5v1AD6LZPEI4LVa4um0uLMbA6LOZvTXnBgQh7Aiw/edit#gid=281278509

I want the total price in Column I  (Price in row=2, qty in N10 to CG199)

I was able to get it in I12 by

=SUMPRODUCT(N12:CG12,N$2:CG$2)

but I want to ignore the blue columns (with Row 7=true and row 202 not equal to "NO")

I tried (in I10) (took help from https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/sumproduct-if/ )

=SUMPRODUCT(if(or(N$7:CG$7=false,N$202:CG$202="NO"),N10:CG10*N$2:CG$2))

I'm not able to get an OR condition inside the if condition.

Comment: afaik, If your file is to be (run,stored and) used as googlesheet, that Excel Array formula wouldn't work. is the file is to be used on both environment or ultimately just google sheet?

Answer (score 2):

Sticking with `SUMPRODUCT` (i.e., what you are already familiar with) and editing only for your logic, see if this works for you:

`=SUMPRODUCT(N12:CG12, N$2:CG$2, (N$7:CG$7<>TRUE)+(N$202:CG$202="NO")>0)`